# Using mylyn outside eclipse - task management/time tracking tool

Tags: task, bug-tracking, time-tracking, task-management

I left Eclipse over two year ago in favor of Jetbrains products (PhpStorm and RubyMine). The only feature I miss from Eclipse is [Mylyn](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide). Until now I use it only for convenience in organizing things, what I need now for a project is its time tracking feature.

Is there any way to use Mylyn outside Eclipse?

Alternatively, is there any **automatic** tool/plugin for Jetbrains IDE (or for the OS itself, in my case OS X) which tracks spent time inside projects/tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Tasktop Technologies.

You can use Tasktop's standalone application to track time.  Tasktop has the added advantage that it can also track non-code artifacts (like spreadsheets, documents, presentations, images, etc.) and keep track of them but connected to your task.  (In Mylyn-speak, it will add them to your context.)

There is not a Mylyn-esque plugin for Jetbrains IDE that I know of.

Comment: I wrote more than once to Tasktop support, asking both for Mac version of your product and to get more information if your program will ever be integrated with other products (such as JB IDEs), I never received an answer... Moreover, I think that TaskTop can track time, but cannot track spent time inside my IDE, so I need to start and stop time tracking manually, this would be a pain...